Question about a question about LEGO games for grown-ups
There is a (non-meta) question I'd like to ask, but I think it could be seen as too subjective. So I prefer to ask here whether it would be acceptable: at the very least, this question would be useful in view of similar, future questions.
   The question (I am not asking it here!) is:

LEGO Games for Grown-ups
  Are all LEGO Boardgames more or less for children, or are some of them suitable for grown-up, more expert players? (Everybody likes relaxing with a simple game, but are any of the games a bit more challenging?)


Yes, I think that question should be fine - and I can think of at least two non-subjective answers to it ;)

Very well! Thanks for settling my doubts.

I don't have any problem with this question either, expect for the fact it may also be a good fit for boardgames.se. Whether it would be a better fit, I don't know - are non-LEGO people really playing these?

Not all LEGO Games are boardgames - Shave A Sheep and the new Chicken game (Kokoriko) aren't boardgames so much as dice games - and they don't seem to mention those sorts of games as explicitly "on topic" as far as I can see, even if they could be.

I sort of assumed any non-computer games would be on-topic, including dice games; after all card games are also represented. I guess we should take the time to chat a bit with the admins there and see what they think about it.

Yeah, looking deeper, I think they probably would be although it's hard to find any other examples (not really knowing the names of any beyond Yahtzee), however equally I think in the same way that while questions about Apple stuff could be "on-topic" for Super User they are directed to Apple.SE - similarly for LEGO questions - although I guess it depends on the core focus of the question
